# Windows Driver Timestamp function

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver, device-driver

I am modifying an existing Windows Kernel device driver and in there I need to capture a timestamp.  I was intending to use time.h library and call the clock() function to get that, however under windows visual studio, the linking is failing.  So I took it as a means that I need to work within the driver's libraries.

I found the following function, KeInitializeTimer, and KeSetTimerEx but these are used if I plan to set up a timer and wake up on it.  What I really need is something that will give me a timestamp.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think I found an answer to my own question.  I found these two kernel APIs which should meet my needs, KeQueryTickCount() and KeQuerySystemTime()

Comment: Assuming that works (which I think it should) please post this as an answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am updating my question with an answer for others to benefit from my findings.

To get a timestamp, you can use KeQueryTickCount(). This routine will give you the count of interval interrupts that occurred since the system was booted.  However, if you need to find out since the last timestamp you captured, an X amount of time has passed you need to also query your system to determine the time it takes for each interval clock interrupt.

ULONG KeQueryTimeIncrement()  give you the number of 100-nanosecond units.

Example:

```
PLARGE_INTEGER timeStamp;

KeQueryTickCount(&timeStamp);
```

Please note that PLARGE_INTEGER is defined as such:

```
#if defined(MIDL_PASS)
typedef struct _LARGE_INTEGER {
#else // MIDL_PASS
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        ULONG LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
    struct {
        ULONG LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } u;
#endif //MIDL_PASS
    LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;
```

So lets say, you want to see if 30 seconds passed since you last took a timestamp, you can do the following:

```
ULONG tickIncrement, ticks;
LARGE_INTEGER waitTillTimeStamp;
tickIncrement = KeQueryTimeIncrement();
```

// 1sec is 1,000,000,000 nano sec, however, since KeQueryTimeIncrement is in 
// 100ns increments, divide that and your constant is 10,000,000

```
ticks = ((30 * 10,000,000) / tickIncrement);
KeQueryTickCount(&waitTillTimeStamp);
waitTillTimeStamp.QuadPart += ticks;

<.....Some code and time passage....>
KeQueryTickCount(&currTimeStamp);


if (waitTillTimeStamp.QuadPart < currTimeStamp.QuadPart) {
    <...Do whatever...>
}
```

Another example to help you understand this, what if you want to translate the timestamp you got into a time value such as milliseconds.

```
LARGE_INTEGER mSec, currTimeStamp;
ULONG timeIncrement;

timeIncrement = KeQueryTimeIncrement();


KeQueryTickCount(&currTimeStamp);

// 1 millisecond is 1,000,000 nano seconds, but remember divide by 100 to account for 
// KeQueryTickCount granularity.
mSec.QuadPart = (currTimeStamp.QuadPart * timeIncrement) / 10000;
```

Remember this example is for demonstration purposes, mSec is not the current time in milliseconds.  Based on the APIs used above, it is merely the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the system was started.

You can also use GetTickCount(), but this returns a DWORD and thus will only be able to give you the number of milliseonds since the system was started for up to 49.7 days.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a 10 years old question but... better later than never. I disagree with the OP's answer.

Proper solution:

```
// The KeQuerySystemTime routine obtains the current system time.
LARGE_INTEGER SystemTime;              
KeQuerySystemTime(&SystemTime);

// The ExSystemTimeToLocalTime routine converts a GMT system time value to the local system time for the current time zone.
LARGE_INTEGER LocalTime;
ExSystemTimeToLocalTime(&SystemTime, &LocalTime);

// The RtlTimeToTimeFields routine converts system time into a TIME_FIELDS structure.
TIME_FIELDS TimeFields;
RtlTimeToTimeFields(&LocalTime, &TimeFields);
```

Comment: Both answers are useful. Having the actual system time can be helpful if you want to compare driver events with other processes or events on other machines. Tick counts are useful for elapsed time and ignores fluctuations in the system time that can happen if you have a flaky time standard updating the system clock.