# KeQueryTickCount Proper Usage

Tags: c, windows, kernel

In my driver I need it to wait for about 30 seconds. I want to use KeQueryTickCount to do that. Right now all I want to do is get a proper return value from the function which I cannot do. Here is what I've tried:

```
// this causes bsod
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject,PUNICODE_STRING pRegistryPath)
{
    PLARGE_INTEGER TickCount1 = NULL;
    KeQueryTickCount(TickCount1);
}
```

And then...

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject,PUNICODE_STRING pRegistryPath)
{
    PLARGE_INTEGER TickCount1 = NULL;
    KeQueryTickCount(&TickCount1);
}
// this generates compiler error:
//Left of '->HighPart' must point to struct/union
```

The only other similar question I could find is : [Windows Driver Timestamp function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12983345/windows-driver-timestamp-function)

So I tried this:

```
#if defined(MIDL_PASS)
typedef struct _LARGE_INTEGER {
#else // MIDL_PASS
typedef union _LARGE_INTEGER {
    struct {
        ULONG LowPart;
        LONG HighPart;
    } DUMMYSTRUCTNAME;
struct {
    ULONG LowPart;
    LONG HighPart;
} u;
#endif //MIDL_PASS
    LONGLONG QuadPart;
} LARGE_INTEGER;
// This generates this error
//'_LARGE_INTEGER' : 'union' type redefinition
```

My compiler is MS DDK 7600.16385.1 x86 free build environment win 7

Can anyone show me a full working code sample for this function, or what full working code should look like to call this API? Thank you for your help.

EDIT - Here is the proper answer to this:

```
for (i = 0; i < 30*1000*20; i++)
{
    KeStallExecutionProcessor(50);
}
```

Comment: You want to wait for 30 seconds in a driver?

Comment: If you can't work out how to call this function from the msdn docs, then I suggest that you might be out of your depth working in kernel mode. I'd recommend doing some user mode Windows programming first.

Comment: @MartinJames: _"You want to wait for 30 seconds in a driver?"_ That must have been the funniest quote I've read in a while. :-)

Comment: Stewart, before commenting again you should understand that many of these kernel functions have no reliable documentation.

Comment: Um - this one does. It is linked in my answer. If a kernel mode function is not reliably documented on MSDN (which is very good by the way) then it is probably not meant to be called.

Comment: The edit is not the proper answer to the question. it is an answer (although not the proper one) to some other question which you did not ask.

Comment: Stuart - that is INCORRECT. If you compiled this you'd see that code waits for 30 seconds and is the proper way. Your way didn't work - it BSOD's, but you didn't compile and test to see that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The right way to call it is as follows:-

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject,PUNICODE_STRING pRegistryPath)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER TickCount1 = {};
    KeQueryTickCount(&TickCount1);
}
```

@Martin James is quite right however - waiting 30 seconds in a driver by spinning on the tick count is a bad idea.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff553071(v=vs.85).aspx is the documentation for the function

Comment: To be fair, the OP doesn't say he's planning to spin.  He may just mean that he's going to record the tick count at some point, and later on compare it to see whether 30 seconds have passed.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - quite true.

Comment: This still causes a crash

Comment: Stewart, in every full program I've seen using this function, there are dependent structs which you seem to not include. I've included a way that actually works and not just copy/pasted from some where in my main question, but thanks for trying ; )

Comment: Sorry, I'm not at all clear what you're saying here. I did copy and paste the code from your question - then I fixed it. There is nothing wrong with the code above. Your question was "How do I call KeQueryTickCount" if I'm not mistaken. What you've added is some unrelated code about how to spin in a driver, which is a terrible terrible terrible idea by the way.

Comment: Stuart, this answer is INCORRECT. Go compile it and run on winx32 free build compiler and it will compile, but causes a crash. Plus you have no idea what I'm even trying to do. Thank you for trying though, next time test first : )

Comment: I did test it. It works for me. What crash do you get?